# value as ID in an input text

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have the following input

```
<input id="result" ng-model="upload.documentURL" type="text" name="recievedDate"> <br></form>
```

where the id="result" refers to the javascript line that would provide the input its value

```
 var message =  url;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = message;
```

In other words, I want the value of the input to refer the message provided written in the javascript line.

However, I am not sure how to achieve this.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: replace `innerHTML` with `value` !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript get input text value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/javascript-get-input-text-value)

Comment: thank you so much. I apologize for my noob. How would I hide the input so its not visible by the eye of the public?

Comment: Add the `type=hidden` attribute. Or, perhaps better, use css.

Comment: You want a hidden input not a text, so change `type=text` to `type=hidden`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

input tags do not conatin any text content. innerHTML is not helpful. input tags use a `value` attrubute instead:

```
<input id="result" value="foo">
```

And so your JavaScript to adgust that argument:

```
document.getElementById('result').value = url;
```

Comment: This answer is now just a copy of the above.

Answer (score 4):

You can not use innerHTML for the input type. If you have to set the value for the input then you have to use the follwing code :

```
var message =  url;

document.getElementById('result').value = message;
```